# TensorFlow neural net outputs linear function

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I implemented a basic MLP and I want it to predict a user-generated set of data, but the prediction looks as follows:

[image: prediction].

I am not sure why... I have nonlinearities in the hidden layers, and I tried multiple activations (`ReLU`, `tanh`, `sigmoid`), tried different optimisers, different learning rates, various architectures (more layers, fewer layers, dropout), but I never got this right.

Please note that I do believe it may be because of how I compute the predictions at the end (`pred = sess.run(out, feed_dict={inputs:X.reshape(n_input, 1)})`) as it may be incorrect, but I wouldn't know why. I also tried other methods like extracting the weights with `w = sess.run(weights)` and then feeding them to the `model()` function along with the input, but nothing worked.

Also, when monitoring the error, the error decreases between epochs.

Any ideas?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Architecture
input_size = 1
output_size = 1
h1_size = 20
h2_size = 50

# 2 hidden layers network
def model(inputs, weights):
    out1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, weights['h1']))
    out2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(out1, weights['h2']))
    return tf.matmul(out2, weights['h3'])

# Inputs/label placeholders
inputs = tf.placeholder('float', shape=(None, input_size))
labels = tf.placeholder('float', shape=(None, output_size))

# Learnable weights
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(input_size, h1_size))),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(h1_size, h2_size))),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(h2_size, output_size))),
}

# Stores the result from the net
out = model(inputs, weights)

# Cost and optimisation
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(out - labels))
opt = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer()
opt_operation = opt.minimize(cost)


# Generate some data
n_input = 1000

X = np.linspace(0, 1, n_input).astype('f')
y = X + 5 * np.sin(X * 10)
y /= max(y)

# Train
epochs = 2000
lr = 0.0000001

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(epochs):        
        _, c = sess.run([opt_operation, cost], feed_dict={
            inputs: X.reshape(n_input, 1),
            labels: y.reshape(n_input, 1),
        })

        if not epoch % int(epochs/20):    
            print(c)

    pred = sess.run(out, feed_dict={inputs:X.reshape(n_input, 1)})
    plt.scatter(X, pred, color='red', label='prediction')    
    plt.scatter(X, y, label='data')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot bias terms: [new graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMC9o.png)

It works now but not sure if this fixed it?

New code uses:

```
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(input_size, h1_size))),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(h1_size, h2_size))),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(h2_size, output_size))),

    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[1])),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[1])),
}
```

and

```
def model(inputs, weights):
    out1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, weights['h1']) + weights['b1'])
    out2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(out1, weights['h2']) + weights['b2'])
    return tf.matmul(out2, weights['h3'] + weights['b3'])
```